# Muscle pain when i do racewalking

Tags: running, racewalking

On the spotted zone marked in red below, I get pain after 4-5 days of race-walking. Sometimes it hurts only while walking or racewalking. But today I can`t even run.

[image]

I got a problem there before athletics from football and tennis, I guess.

I need some opinions on what could have caused it and suggestions on how to avoid it from happening again.

Could it be from increasing the intensity of training in the last 3 months?
From 10 km/day 4 days/week, now I do 15-20 km/day 6 days/week.

Answer (score 3):

**DISCLAIMER:** I am not a doctor, nor do I claim any sort of medical expertise.  If you are experiencing discomfort beyond normal soreness, I would recommend seeing a competent doctor.  I merely intend to impart my personal insights and experience.

I'm not sure if I understand "Where is the red spoted zone", but the picture you provided is pointing to the sartorius (the upper line) as well as the quadricep ("quad" - the lower line).  If both of these are hurting it's probably two separate issues that could've been caused by any number of things.  The sartorius connects the interior knee to the anterior (outside) hip.  If you're consistently getting problems with this, your spine could be out of alignment which is causing your hip to pull in an unnatural direction.  As stated before, I would suggest seeing a competent chiropractor/sports medicine doctor.

I consider myself to be an above-average runner, but I've never run the 15-20k/day for 6 days/week as you mentioned. Your body needs rest and time to recover.  If you don't let your muscles recover, after time they become stressed and incredibly susceptible to increased injury (especially when there might be an existing injury that's been neglected).

[This article](http://runningresearchnews.com/News_And_Events.php?cid=1&iid=162) talks about the necessities of recovery and how it might vary from person to person.  It might give you a better idea of how to maximize your recovery and workouts.

My suggestion: see a doctor.  Determine what the issue is, then when you've fixed it, you can ask for better help about how to avoid it.